# How to use \char inside \pdfinfo?

Tags: symbols, metadata

First of all, I *would like* to avoid `hyperref` package.

I'm using

```
\AtEndDocument{
    \pdfinfo{
        /Title (here (\the\year))
        /Creator (foo)
        %   /Producer (pdfTeX 1.40.0)
        /Author (\@author)
        /Subject (foo)
        /Keywords (faa,foo)
    }
}
```

to pass some info to the PDF file.

But I also wish to write some chars inside (to be not so explicit), like `\char'151\char'141` for example.

But in this case the output is **(2016) char '151char '141**.

Is it possible to hide chars inside `pdfinfo`?

Comment: You should either use `^^` notation or `\Uchar` in LuaTeX (or XeLaTeX). But `\char` is not expandable. Why exactly do you need that? Can't you define `\def\hiddencharone{a}` and `\def\hiddenchartwo{b}` and use `\hiddencharone\hiddenchartwo`?

Comment: Could you make a better example or is the author's name a secret?

Comment: @egreg, I'd like to make difficulty to students to edit the class and change the meta data. Using those lot of chars could keep the students away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\char` is not an expandable command, thus it does not work as string in `\pdfinfo`. Also, `\char` would use the current font encoding. But the font encoding is irrelevant here. Instead, the PDF specification allows two encodings:

- PDFDocEncoding, an 8-bit encoding, different, but similar to latin1,
- UTF16-BE with BOM for Unicode strings

Package `stringenc` helps in converting a string (e.g. from UTF-8) to the correct encoding, needed for the values in `\pdfinfo`.

Also the values for the keys in `\pdfinfo` must be escaped as strings, for example unmatched parentheses; pdfTeX's `\pdfescapestring` helps here for strings given in parentheses.
The other string form are angle brackets with the string encoded as hexadecimal string.

Package `hyperref`'s `\pdfstringdef` takes care of lots of these issues. It also defines virtual font encodings `PD1` and `PU` to get many characters work. For reinventing the wheel I strongly recommend reading the section about strings in the [PDF specification](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html).

At TeX level, the string needs to expand as plain text string without commands. PDF viewers do not know about TeX commands inside bookmark strings.

The letters by `\char'151` (`i`) and `\char'141` (`a`) can be given as (PDFDocEncoding):

```
\pdfinfo{/Author(\string\151\string\141)}
```

`pdfinfo` reports then:

```
Author: ia
```

Comment: I'll take a look on those refs. By the way, latin1 is good for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Sigur Some characters are different, the PDFDocEncoding is listed in an appendix of the PDF reference.

Comment: It worked perfectly! I tried `\expandafter` and `\protect` without working, thanks to my pour knowledge. But I forgot about `\string`. Thanks.